# How to sort items in a list using foreach C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, foreach

I need to sort the items I have in a list by age using foreach in ascending order, and so I have no idea how to. This is my code so far:

```
namespace ListProject
{
    public struct FamilyMem
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;

        public FamilyMem(string name,int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FamilyMem Jack = new FamilyMem("Jack", 15);
            FamilyMem Tom = new FamilyMem("Tommy", 24);
            FamilyMem Felix = new FamilyMem("Felix", 26);
            FamilyMem Lukas = new FamilyMem("Lukas", 26);
            FamilyMem Austin = new FamilyMem("Austin", 54);
            FamilyMem Ben = new FamilyMem("Ben", 55);

            List<FamilyMem> gambleList = new List<FamilyMem>();

            gambleList.Add(Jack);
            gambleList.Add(Tom);
            gambleList.Add(Felix);
            gambleList.Add(Lukas);
            gambleList.Add(Austin);
            gambleList.Add(Ben);

            Console.WriteLine(gambleList.Count.ToString());


        }
    }
}
```

I also need a separate piece of code that will allow me to sort the names alphabetically. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at *Linq* `OrderBy`

Comment: One thing you can do to shorten this code while I'm thinking about it: you can use collection initializer syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't edit a collection while you're iterating over it with a foreach loop, so this much at least isn't possible. You can, however, use LINQ or some for loops. Use something like:

```
gambleList = gambleList.OrderBy(item => item.name).ToList();
```

The reason for the assignment, by the way, is that the OrderBy operation (unlike, for example, the `Sort()` method) does *not* sort the collection in place - it returns a reference to a sorted collection.

You could also use a standard for loop or recursive function to implement something like an Insertion Sort.

Comment: We don't need to use .ToList() again. Since it's already a list. 
Simply `gambleList.OrderBy(x => x.age);` is fine.

Comment: @Ripon that isn't correct. The actual return type of OrderBy is System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> (*not* list) and there is no implicit conversion from that to List; thus, if you omit the ToList in the code I provided it won't even compile. And besides, LINQ makes heavy use of deferred/lazy evaluation, so the query won't even occur until you iterate over the list somehow. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ EJoshuaS my whole point is that gambleList is already a list. So, why we need to assign that list again. We simply can sort and we do not need to assign it back. I never said your answer is not correct.

Comment: @Ripon OrderBy doesn't order items in place (unlike, for example, the Sort method). If you try simply doing 'gambleList.OrderBy(x => x.age);' without the assignment you'll see that gambleList remains unchanged.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look for Linq. Just simply google it. 
You can do this using OrderBy as follows:

```
gambleList = gambleList.OrderBy(x => x.age).ToList();
```

Comment: You have to do "gambleList = gambleList.OrderBy(item => item.name).ToList();" as OrderBy doesn't sort the list in place; this code will leave gambleList unchanged. Also the OP wants to sort them alphabetically so presumably he wants to sort by name rather than age.

Comment: Well it can be interchanged from item.name to item.age depending on how I want to sort them

Comment: People do google it and then stackoverflow comes up in the results. LOL

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you taking a look at some IEnumerable methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) and some examples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort

Example:

```
Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
               new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
               new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);

foreach (Pet pet in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
}
```

Comment: If you can't comment, then don't try to shoehorn a comment into an answer. Answers should be reserved for actual answers, not getting around the system.

Comment: Okay. Sorry about that.